# Sendgrid SendEmailAsync Response Content is always null

Tags: .net, .net-core, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid NuGet package to trigger the email. The email gets triggered successfully and I receive the email as well, however, when I want to see the response content of it, it is returning an empty string

await response.DeserializeResponseBodyAsync(response.Body);

the above code is always null

Is anyone else is also facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Based on their [API Reference](https://sendgrid.com/docs/api-reference/) if send email success then response code is 202 and there is no body for this status. Body is present when status is not 202. You can see it in *Responses* section.

Comment: Thanks. How do we manage the webhooks then, if there no unique id of message, how do we update different statuses of a user?